# Spark - Filters over values of column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a Spark`s DataFrame with two columns, as such:

```
A | B
--+--
a | 1
a | 2
a | 3
b | 1
b | 4
c | 2
```

I want to create another dataframe by filtering this one by the unique values on the column `A`. Currently, I'm collecting the values and adding to a list, as such:

```
As = [x.A for x in df.select("A").distinct().collect()]
```

that would yield: `As: ['a', 'b', 'c']`

and filtering the original data frame like this:

```
for a in As:
    filtered_df = df.filter(df.A == a)
```

so, at first iteration, I would have a new dataframe like this:

```
A | B
--+--
a | 1
a | 2
a | 3
```

in the second iteration, like this:

```
A | B
--+--
b | 1
b | 4
```

and so on.

Since this triggers a `collect()`, i'm trying to think in a way that this would not be needed.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @mtoto Edited. Sorry about this.

Comment: you are only collecting unique values, which is not expensive and a valid way to do this.

Comment: That's great to know! Thanks! (If you think this deserves a complete answer, I will gladly mark it as the right one)

Comment: @mtoto Well, it can be in general. But filtering in loop will be much worse most of the time.

Comment: @ArthurCamara What is the end goal here?

Comment: @zero323 I can't disclosure the actual data, but I'm filtering the data frame in order to calculate a bunch of stuff over it (a couple of means and sums, basically). I could simply apply the calculations using a 'where()' , but I can't change the calculations code itself. I have to pass the filtered data frame to it, since it may be called without any filters or, eventually, with more complex filters.

Comment: Why not use `groupBy` -> `agg`? In general this should significantly more efficient.

Comment: As an update, I ended up implementing everything as `groupby -> agg`. The previous version of the code took about an hour to run. Now, it's down to about 45~60 seconds (after collecting the results, for a (less un)fair comparison)